# My WoW account was hacked! What should I do?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, battle.net

Recently a player named **"Blizzardi"** whisperd me saying there were security problems with my account and I had to visit a webpage or my account would be banned. There was a [GM] tag next to his name...

**You guessed it!** I fell for the trick and **gave away some of my account data** on a site that was **EXACTLY IDENTICAL** to the Battle.net interface. I am new to the game so I expected it to be something necessary for an update or something.

My highest level character was 50 and had around 350g which is not really worth stealing, but my characters do not matter to me. What matters is my account and private information!

Once I realized that I got hacked, I wrote a help ticket about account recovery to Blizzard. They responded earlier this evening. They told me, that I had to send them another ticket containing my new information (account name, email etc.). I just got done sending them my new stuff and realized that the tickets I send weren't showing up in the "tickets" tab. (Is it because the hacker turned of my communication feauture?)

I did some research and found out that "Blizzardi" is becoming a famous threat on the WoW forums.

Another strange thing that I found out was that all of my characters were gone. Only one remained...one i didn't create. Guess what his name was? "Blizzardi", a level 1 Warrior -_-

Please tell me what i should do now in order to recover my lost account and data.

Thank you in advance dear stack-gaming community! <3

Comment: Change your password if you haven't already.

Answer (score 21):

If you used your Battle.net password for anything else (e-mail, Steam, other accounts), change those passwords ASAP.

Other than that, it sounds like you've already done exactly what you need to do: [Contact Blizzard](http://us.battle.net/en/security/help) and they'll help you with the recovery process.

The [account recovery page](https://us.battle.net/account/support/account-recovery.html) will help you regain access to your Battle.net account. Once you've done that, you can start restoring your characters.

Comment: i've already done that :)

Comment: Just changed all passwords i had to other-ones. What next?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what everyone else suggested: If you have a smartphone, [get the Battle.net Authenticator app](http://us.blizzard.com/support/article.xml?locale=en_US&articleId=24660&pageNumber=1) for it. If you don't have a smartphone, you can purchase an authenticator from Blizzard.

This way, even if someone else knows your password, they won't be able to access your account unless they *also* have your authenticator with them.

Hope you get it fixed.

Comment: I recommend the standalone Authenticator over the phone apps for one simple reason: if your phone gets hosed and you can't do a complete restore for some reason, you are locked out until you can reach a human being on the Blizzard help line and that can take hours or even days depending on when it happens.

Comment: @Mr.Muskrat: You can avoid the "can't do a restore" issue completely by using a service like Dropbox to store your restore credentials.

Answer (score 3):

Basically the only thing you can do is go through Blizzard's ticket process.  Appeal as often as you have too.  A recommendation for the future is to realize that GM's do not message you telling you that it is time to get banninated.

Comment: I've gone through it multiple times in different languages neither of the tickets were shown in my tickets tab :(

Comment: If you have a hard copy of the game get a hold of blizzard using that game code, if it is the digital one get a hold of the credit card you used to purchase it and that should allow them to crosscheck the information.  I would recommend creating a brand new email address for this process.

Comment: I only have the digital version since i update the "up-to-lvl-20"-version :S

Comment: The tickets may not show up right away (or at all) - especially for account recovery, if someone else has access to your account, Blizzard doesn't want to show them you've initiated recovery. Keep an eye on your email associated with your account, though.
Seriously, though, the account recovery form is THE way to get control of your account again.